# How can I prevent or avoid this error "Uncaught TypeError: event.date.format is not a function"?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, bootstrap-4

When I select a date and try to empty or clear it in the textbox then click in any part of the page, I received this error "Uncaught TypeError: event.date.format is not a function". How can avoid this error? Can somebody help me with my problem? This is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5nq3vmzg/1/

```
$('.datepicker').on('dp.change', function(event) {
  var date = event.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  console.log(date);
  Vue.set(vm, 'date', date);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When field is empty `event.date === false`, so try to check if `event.date` is not equals to `false` before formating it.

```
$('.datepicker').on('dp.change', function(event) {
  if (event.date) {
    var date = event.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(date);
    Vue.set(vm, 'date', date);
  }
});
```